# Is there a command to list all examples of shiny package?

Tags: r, shiny

I am learning shiny package to develop web application. I found some of the default example. But i want to list all examples of shiny

Comment: Examples where? I don't understand what you're asking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could visit this page: https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/

.......